Minimalist encoding of a Turing machine
Can a Turing machine that can only write only 1 or 0 simulate any algorithm?
I came up with this way to encode an input-output Turing machine, though I'm sure I'm not the only one who has thought of it. It's either well-known already, or perhaps I'm missing something and it doesn't work.
We'll start with a two-state machine, so you only need 1 bit to encode the states 0 and 1. In this case, the 1st 9 bits tell the machine what to do in state 0, and the next 9 bits tell the machine what to do in state 1. We need to tell the machine what to do when it sees a ⊔, 0, or 1. It looks like this, where w is write, m is move and q is state:
0: {⊔ => wmq, 0 => wmq, 1 => wmq}
The machine: 000 110 001, means:
$$ Q = \{0,1\} $$
$$ \Sigma = \{0,1\} $$
$$ \Gamma = \{0,1,⊔\} $$
Delta can be described like this: on ⊔ write 0, move right, stay in state 0. On 0 write 1, move left, stay in state 0. On 1 write 0 move right, and move to state 1. Since state 1 isn't defined, it halts.
$$ \text{Start State} = 0 $$
$$ \text{Halt} = 1 $$
If the string had exactly 18 bits, it would never halt because every action is defined and there is no halt state. If the string is larger than 18 bits it will need more bits to encode the states. Up to 48 bits, 2 bits are used so each state definition is 4*3=12 bits long. Up to 120 bits, 3 bits are needed. This follows the formula:
$$3(2^x)(2+x)=L$$
where x is the number of bits used to encode the state and L is the length of the string. (This can't be solved algebraically, so numerical methods will need to be used.)
Some advantages of this encoding is that every string is a valid Turing machine. (This was the whole purpose of me thinking of this.)
Some things it can't do is write a blank. It also can't take any input as it doesn't have a way of knowing which part of the string should be the input. I figure that any finite input could be generated by the first part of the Turing machine, and the machine could then move to the next phase where it acts on the input.
My question is, given the limitations of this encoding, is it Turing complete? Can a machine written this way do everything a Turing machine can?
We could expand upon this model. Rather than just 1 and 0 you could theoretically expand the string alphabet to include more symbols by designating more bits to represent each symbol and expanding each state to account for the additional symbols. So you can write 00, 01, 10, or 11, thus giving you 4 symbols. One of them could represent a blank and another could be used as a marker.
Edit: my guess is this isn't Turing complete because you can't mark any symbols. This could be fixed by using the 4 symbol version.

I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you mean that the finite-state control has only 2 states, or that the tape alphabet has only two symbols, or the input alphabet has only two symbols, or some combination of multiple of those?  What does "the 1st 9 bits" refer to?  "the 1st 9 bits" of what?  I don't know what "the string" refers to, or what "it will need more bits to encode the states" means.  Some context seems missing.  This post is long and it seems like a lot to expect anyone to read the entire thing.  Please don't use "Edit:"; just revise your question so it reads well.

Consider a Turing machine $M$ with finite sets of states $Q$ and tape symbols $\Gamma$, and a transition function $\delta$. Encode each possible transition $t_j$ in $M$ by a unique prime $p_j$. A transition $t_j$ is determined by $(q_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}}, s_{\text{next}}, d)$, where $q_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}} \in Q$, $s_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{next}} \in \Gamma$, and $d \in \{\text{Left}, \text{Right}\}$. Let
$$ \alpha_j = f(q_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}}, s_{\text{next}}, d) $$
be a bijective encoding of this 5-tuple as a single natural number via a standard pairing function, such as the Cantor pairing function, composed multiple times. For example, we can assign a unique natural number code to each element of $Q$, $\Gamma$, and $\{\text{Left}, \text{Right}\}$, then use the Cantor pairing function $\pi(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)(x+y+1) + y$ as follows:

$ a = \pi(\text{code}(q_{\text{current}}), \text{code}(s_{\text{current}}))$
$ b = \pi(\text{code}(q_{\text{next}}), \text{code}(s_{\text{next}}))$
$ c = \pi(b, \text{code}(d))$
$\alpha_j = f(q_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}}, s_{\text{next}}, d) = \pi(a, c)$

Define an overall code
$$ E(M) = \prod_j p_j^{\alpha_j}, $$
where the product extends over every transition $t_j$ in $M$. Represent $E(M)$ on a binary-only tape by writing its base-10 digits $d_1 \dots d_k$ in binary, including binary delimiters (e.g., "1111") to separate consecutive decimal digits, using a fixed number of bits (e.g., 4 bits) for each decimal digit.
Construct a universal machine $U$ that operates purely in the binary alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ and does the following:

Interprets the tape contents as a string of decimal digits $d_1 \dots d_k$ of $E(M)$.
Uses long division and repeated subtraction in binary to detect for each prime $p_j$ the largest exponent $\alpha_j$ such that $p_j^{\alpha_j}$ divides $E(M)$.
Reconstructs every transition of $M$. This is done by applying the inverse function $f^{-1}$ to each $\alpha_j$ to obtain the original 5-tuple $(q_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}}, s_{\text{next}}, d)$. Since $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}$ is well-defined.

Step (2) can be carried out via elementary computations in binary: integer division, primality checks, and exponent counting are all partial recursive functions, hence can be computed by some Turing machine on $\{0, 1\}$ alone.
Once $U$ has recovered $\alpha_j$ for each $j$, it obtains the full transition table of $M$ and simulates $M$ step-by-step on a separate work region of the tape. Whenever $M$'s head in state $q_{\text{current}}$ scans symbol $s_{\text{current}}$, the machine $U$ references the $\alpha_j$ that encodes the transition $(q_{\text{current}}, s_{\text{current}}, q_{\text{next}}, s_{\text{next}}, d)$. It writes the correct symbol $s_{\text{next}}$ on the work tape (only 0 or 1, encoding the symbols of $M$ in binary), updates its own internal binary-encoded "state" to match $q_{\text{next}}$, and shifts its simulated head location one cell left or right, also tracked in binary. This process continues until $M$ would halt.
Since $U$ itself is a Turing machine that writes only the symbols 0 and 1 but can perform prime factorization and all associated arithmetic (including encoding/decoding using $f$ and $f^{-1}$), it follows that a machine restricted to writing 0 and 1 can indeed simulate any algorithm.
Therefore, a binary Turing machine is Turing complete.
